# How do I set the date on the datetimepicker to today without changing the time

Tags: c#, datetimepicker

If I do this:

dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Today;

The date gets set to today's date but the time gets
set to 12:00:00 AM.  I don't want the time to be changed.

Any help appreciated (I searched quite a bit for this)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [according MSDN-site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.today(v=vs.110).aspx) states, DateTime.Today is:

> An object that is set to today's date, with the time component set to **00:00:00.**

This means you have to "save" your time before setting the new `DateTime`:

```
dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Today.Add(dateTimePicker1.Value.TimeOfDay);
```

This now adds the time of your `DateTimePicker` to your date with the time 12:00:00AM / 00:00:00, meaning it gets set to the time before.